# After re.split, how to put separators back?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

the following code take apart the equation and assemble it after sorting it.

```
def simplify(poly):
    import re
    p=re.split('\+|\-',poly)
    return '+'.join(sorted(''.join(sorted(x)) for x in p))
print(simplify('a+ca-ab'))
```

problem : It's not hard to sort them, but it's difficult to put the operator (+,-) back, the code above can only put back the '+' but not the '-' back into the equation.

May I ask how should I put the operators back?

Comment: Your code isn't really simplifying anything. What do you want to do? Simply sorting variable names?

Comment: Yeah for now just sort the unknowns in lexicographic order then assemble it

Comment: Okay. I think my solution answers your question.

Comment: I'm still looking at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your function name doesn't suit the code. You're only trying to sort the unknowns in lexicographic order.

If you separate the unknowns and their sign, the processing will become a mess. Just process them together:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('[+-]?[a-z]+', re.I)

def ignore_sign(s):
    return re.sub('[+-]', '', s)

def simplify(poly):
    if poly[0] not in '+-':
        poly = '+' + poly
    parts = [''.join(sorted(part)) for part in re.findall(pattern, poly)]
    sorted_parts = sorted(parts, key=ignore_sign)
    return re.sub('^\+', '', ''.join(sorted_parts))

print(simplify('a-ac+ba'))
# a+ab-ac
```

A `+` is prepended to the string in order to avoid mixing unknowns together (thanks @rici):

```
print(simplify('z-ac+ba'))
# ab-ac+z
```

When sorting the parts, you just need to ignore any sign so that `-a` appears before `+z`:

```
>>> sorted(['-a', '+z'])
['+z', '-a']
>>> sorted(['-a', '+z'], key=ignore_sign)
['-a', '+z']
```

Comment: That works when the first term happens to be minimal, but otherwise you will see an unfortunate concatenation of terms. Better to prepend an explicit `+` to the expression if it doesn't start with a sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic. It will not remove the split character will keep it with list element.

```
import re
def simplify(poly):
    original_p = re.split('(\+|\-)',poly)
    without_operand = [x for x in original_p if x not in ["+", "-"]]
    return "".join(original_p)
print(simplify('a+ca-ab'))
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to sort the unknowns.